# Upload images from gallery

Tags: swift, swift3, swift2

I'm new to swift. I'm creating an app where I need to upload images from gallery. How can I upload MULTIPLE images from gallery to my app. Can someone please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want to use default apple framework Photos FrameWork is to be used for such purpose or you can look for libraries too available for this Purpose , prefer photos framework

Answer (score 0):

Try this may help !!

//Go to Galary for Image picking

```
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = refrenceViewController as! UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        refrenceViewController.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

and also add permission on info.plist and order to access galary

Answer (score 0):

You can only get one image at a time from Apple Photo FrameWork. If you want to allow more then one image then use[Librarys](https://github.com/matteocrippa/awesome-swift). I'm also using [BSImagePicker](https://github.com/mikaoj/BSImagePicker) in one of my one app.